# My home page article links are directing users back to the home page instead of linking to individual articles

Tags: links

It seems that the links on my home page articles are directing users back to the home page instead of linking to individual articles. My website is https://eclipseglassesreview.com/ and i have posted 2 articles which links back to home page. The links are showing correctly in my page showing all of my posts. My permalinks are set to Post name https://eclipseglassesreview.com/sample-post/.

Thanks,
Lee

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to WP Admin -> Permalinks -> Save Changes, It will refresh permalinks.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately that did not work. I even selected "Plain" and hit save to see if that would work which it did not. Than selected post name and save with no luck there either.

Comment: How are you rendering Popular Articles, is this theme default functionality?

Comment: Yes, theme default functionality

Comment: When I am in Elementor, the posts images and links are correct. When I publish the home page, the posts images disappear and the links revert back to the home page.

Comment: Are you using any filter in theme functions file, or using any plugin of URLs related?